# uft type command does not input i character properly

Tags: vbscript, putty, qtp

When running putty commands through UFT i get a problem using type command. The "i" character causes to repeat some string after it sent.

```
Window("PuTTY").Type "cd /kenan/KNCBUST/data/Operation"
Window("PuTTY").Type micReturn
```

Above code returns following input at putty window

```
cknnzi21:/home/arbor : cd /kenan/KNCBUST/data/Operation/on
```

I changed to USA from control panel but it didnt solve anything.

Also same issue if i use Chr(105) instead of "i"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was language of the OS and keyboard. If its set to English it can write commands without problem.